# jquery ui dialog within infoWindow

Tags: jquery-ui, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to use ui dialog within an infoWindow or an infoBox ?
This code doesn't work:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"click", function()
    { 
        html = "$('#dialog-click').dialog({...})";
        ib.setContent(html);
        ib.open(map,marker);
    }


<div id="dialog-click">
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type='text' id='name' />
<label for="firstname">Firstname:</label>
<input type='text' id='firstname' />
</div>
```

Comment: `html` can only be text or text marked up with HTML. Ask yourself, is `"$('#dialog-click').dialog({...})"` HTML?

Comment: I know that this solution doesn't work: it was for giving rise the specialists !

Comment: I was trying to nudge you gently in the right direction. Hopefully the answer by @davidkonrad below will nudge you even further. It's a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you mean *open from within an infoWindow or an infoBox*

Your markup :

```
<div id="dialog-click">
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type='text' id='name' />
<label for="firstname">Firstname:</label>
<input type='text' id='firstname' />
</div>
```

An infowindow :

```
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   map: map
});
```

The map click event :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(args) {
   var html='<a href="#" onclick="$(&quot;#dialog-click&quot;).dialog();">click to open</a>';
   infoWindow.setPosition(args.latLng);        
   infoWindow.setContent(html);
   infoWindow.open(map);
});
```

[image]

Just place the `dialog()`-code in an `onclick`-handler. You can use `args.pixel` to set the position of the  dialog

```
var x=args.pixel.x;
var y=args.pixel.y;
```